# Port forwarding port 21 on a TP-Link

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward port 21 to externally access the FTP server. I followed all the steps correctly to port forward a port but port checker tools still show that the port is blocked.

Port forwarding:

[image: PORT FORWARDING]

Firewall settings:

[image: FIREWALL SETTINGS]

Comment: Have you checked to see if your ISP is blocking any ports?

Comment: if it is blocked try 22 or other port number and tell your ftp client (filezilla or other) to use a diff port

Comment: Port forwarding makes an internal server accessible from the outside. Does it work internally? Perhaps the server has a software firewall that still blocks it? If this is the case, it would not work internally either.

Comment: If your ISP is blocking this port, you should check the fine print on your ISP agreement. It is likely that the ISP forbids you from running FTP, mail, etc. servers on its network. If they discover you are doing this, you may find that your Internet connection just doesn't work one day.